Как узнать тип содержимого переменной в Python?
Есть переменная, как узнать что за ее тп. Строчка или число и тд...
Строчка - число, как строчку в данном случаи преобразовать в число?

Буквальный ответ - type(), isinstance(), int(), float(). Это можно нагуглить за три секунды. Но я вовсе не уверен, что вам это действительно нужно, стоит описать реальную проблему.

Переменная содержит значение но в некоторых случаях возвращает N/A. Пытаюсь разобраться что за тип и попытаться по типу выставить условие. Ничего не выходит...

На гуглил, приводят пример numpy.isnan(), до конца не уверен что это поможет определить факт того что значение равно  N/A . Можете дать комментарий, лишний раз чтобы не устанавливать не удалять модуль. Поможет ли numpy в этом?

Проблема остаётся абстрактной. Приведите примеры "значений", откуда они берутся, и сто вы с ними делаете.

https://superuser.com/questions/1853916/extract-video-bitrate-ffmpeg

N/A означает "недоступно" - т.е. для данного формата параметра битрейта просто не существует. Вы можете проверить строку на равенство "N/A"

Уже, переменную сравнивал Btr == "N/A"

Не работает, не пропускает условие. Думал может по типу как то возможно разобраться...

numpy.isnan() Решит данный вопрос?

Нет, не решит. Выведите принятые данные и посмотрите, что там реально приходит.

<class 'bytes'> если так  type(sub.check_output("ffprobe -i "+file+" -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", shell=True)) b'N/A\n'

Строчка, просто пробелы с начала и конца необходимо было удалить и сравнить со строчкой. А точ что битрейт не вытащить из  webm, очень обидно...

Попробуйте условие 'N/A' in Btr или b'N/A' in Btr.

@Дмитрий все дополнения (пример входных данных) внесите в сам вопрос.

Дополню, что часто вам может понадобиться не просто узнать тип переменной, но и сравнить его с тем типом, который вы ожидаете.
Тогда вам может пригодиться встроенный метод isinstance:
str_result=''
int_result=0
values = [42, '42']
for value in values:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        int_result += value
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        str_result += value
    else:
        raise TypeError('Значения должны быть строковыми или целочисленными')
 



Ответ не отвечает на вопрос "что там в строке, число или нет"?

Чтобы узнать тип содержимого переменной в Python, можно использовать функцию type(). Эта функция возвращает тип объекта, который хранится в переменной.
Пример:
x = 42
print(type(x))  # Выведет: <class 'int'>

y = 3.14
print(type(y))  # Выведет: <class 'float'>

z = "Hello, world!"
print(type(z))  # Выведет: <class 'str'>


Ответ не отвечает на вопрос "что там в строке, число или нет"?

Данная функция определяет, является ли строка числом. Также это можно проверить при помощи регулярок.
def is_num(s):# s - строка
    num = 0
    try:
        num = int(s)
    except ValueError: # Не число
        return False
    else:
        return True # Число

is_num('123') # Число
is_num('abc') # Не число

# Также можно узнать тип переменной функцией type.
type('abc') # str
type('123') # str
type(123) # int
type(1.23) # float


